# \mathparpagebreakable with border and/or caption on each page?

Tags: floats, captions, page-breaking, subfloats, subcaption

I'm using the Ott tool and the [ott-alt](https://github.com/tov/latex-ottalt) package for automatically generating and typesetting a large number of inference rules. Some sets are too large to fit on one page.

The ott-alt package puts them in a `mathparpagebreakable` environment, which is great for allowing them to spread across multiple pages, as well as for automatically adding line-breaks at appropriate points.

However, there's no captions. I can add a title to the start, but someone looking at the second page of rules has no context for which rules they're looking at.

I'm wondering, is there some kind of environment I can wrap this in that will do all or some of the following:

- Wrap the mathpar in a box/border on each page it occurs
- Add a caption to the bottom, or title to the top of each page's version, preferably marking the later pages as "continued"
- Treat them like floats/figures, so they are placed nicely in the text, instead of disrupting the flow, and can be given nice labels and numbers.

The key is that it has to be automatic: the rules are machine generated, so its not feasible for me to go in and insert the page-breaks or split the figures myself.

I'm willing to get into "hack-ish" stuff: I have control over the format of the generated TeX code (to a degree), so if there's something I need to inject into each rule to make this possible, that's likely an option.

EDIT: Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\usepackage{semantic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myrule}{\inference{Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise}{Conclusion}}
\newcommand{\myrulelong}{\inference{Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise}{Conclusion!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{mathparpagebreakable}
\textbf{My rule}\\

\myrule \and
\myrule \and
\myrule \and 
\myrule \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\end{mathparpagebreakable}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `tcolorbox` can solve all three requirements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\usepackage{semantic}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage[]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newcommand{\myrule}{\inference{Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise}{Conclusion}}
\newcommand{\myrulelong}{\inference{Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise\\Premise}{Conclusion!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}}

\newenvironment{mathparpagebreakableboxed}[2][]
  {%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        ,title={#2}
        ,breakable
        ,title after break={#2 (\textit{cont.})}
        ,#1
      ]%
      \begin{mathparpagebreakable}%
  }
  {%
      \end{mathparpagebreakable}%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }

\begin{document}

\blindduck[-]

\begin{mathparpagebreakableboxed}[% additional maybe interesting options
    ,vfill before first%
    %,float % if it should float
  ]{My rule}
\myrule \and
\myrule \and
\myrule \and 
\myrule \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\myrulelong \and 
\end{mathparpagebreakableboxed}

\blindduck[-]

\end{document}
```

You might change some of the default options in `mathparpagebreakableboxed` to your liking.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @jmite note that `tcolorbox` doesn't give any referencable number with just `float` as an option, that would require some additional work (like setting up a counter, refstepping it on each floating box and putting it in the title.

Comment: Looks like the `blend into` option will help with that. I've tried enabling `float`, but for some reason that puts all the figures at the end of the document. I'll keep debugging, but that's definitely a separate issue. Thanks!

Comment: @jmite use `\tcbset{floatplacement=htbp}` in your preamble.